# Powershell Script for 500 errors

Tags: powershell

I want power shell script to fetch all 500 entries from IIS logs from multiple servers. I have written a script that fetches 500 from single servers for previous hours. Could someone check and help me how I can go for fetching multiple servers. Script that I have:

```
#Set Time Variable -60
$time = (Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss"(Get-Date).addminutes(-60))

# Location of IIS LogFile
#$servers = get-content C:\Users\servers.txt
$File = "\\server\D$\Logs\W3SVC89\"+"u_ex"+(get-date).ToString("yyMMddHH")+".log"

# Get-Content gets the file, pipe to Where-Object and skip the first 3 lines.
$Log = Get-Content $File | where {$_ -notLike "#[D,S-V]*" }

# Replace unwanted text in the line containing the columns.
$Columns = (($Log[0].TrimEnd()) -replace "#Fields: ", "" -replace "-","" -replace "\(","" -replace "\)","").Split(" ")

# Count available Columns, used later
$Count = $Columns.Length

# Strip out the other rows that contain the header (happens on iisreset)
$Rows = $Log | where {$_ -like "*500 0 0*"}

# Create an instance of a System.Data.DataTable
#Set-Variable -Name IISLog -Scope Global
$IISLog = New-Object System.Data.DataTable "IISLog"

# Loop through each Column, create a new column through Data.DataColumn and add it to the DataTable
foreach ($Column in $Columns) {
  $NewColumn = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn $Column, ([string])
  $IISLog.Columns.Add($NewColumn)
}

# Loop Through each Row and add the Rows.
foreach ($Row in $Rows) {
  $Row = $Row.Split(" ")
  $AddRow = $IISLog.newrow()
  for($i=0;$i -lt $Count; $i++) {
    $ColumnName = $Columns[$i]
    $AddRow.$ColumnName = $Row[$i]
  }
  $IISLog.Rows.Add($AddRow)
  }
 $IISLog | select @{n="DateTime"; e={Get-Date ("$($_.date) $($_.time)")}},sip,csuristem,scstatus | ? { $_.DateTime -ge $time } |Out-File C:\Users\Servers\results.csv
```

Comment: If your code works well for a single server, I'd put it in a function and call it passing the server as parameter. So you can manage the server list independently from your code. Check what else might be unique such as log path. Finally, if you take this route, ensure you append the results to the CSV with `-append`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your logfile is always on the same path, and that servers.txt contains you server list, 
you can read the server list then execute your code against each one using a foreach loop :
something like that ( a result file is create for each server) :

```
#Set Time Variable -60
$time = (Get-Date -Format "HH:mm:ss"(Get-Date).addminutes(-60))

# Location of IIS LogFile
$servers = get-content C:\Users\servers.txt

$servers| foreach{
    #inside the foreach loop $_ will represent the current server

    $File = "\\$_\D$\Logs\W3SVC89\"+"u_ex"+(get-date).ToString("yyMMddHH")+".log"

    # Get-Content gets the file, pipe to Where-Object and skip the first 3 lines.
    $Log = Get-Content $File | where {$_ -notLike "#[D,S-V]*" }

    # Replace unwanted text in the line containing the columns.
    $Columns = (($Log[0].TrimEnd()) -replace "#Fields: ", "" -replace "-","" -replace "\(","" -replace "\)","").Split(" ")

    # Count available Columns, used later
    $Count = $Columns.Length

    # Strip out the other rows that contain the header (happens on iisreset)
    $Rows = $Log | where {$_ -like "*500 0 0*"}

    # Create an instance of a System.Data.DataTable
    #Set-Variable -Name IISLog -Scope Global
    $IISLog = New-Object System.Data.DataTable "IISLog"

    # Loop through each Column, create a new column through Data.DataColumn and add it to the DataTable
    foreach ($Column in $Columns) {
      $NewColumn = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn $Column, ([string])
      $IISLog.Columns.Add($NewColumn)
    }

    # Loop Through each Row and add the Rows.
    foreach ($Row in $Rows) {
      $Row = $Row.Split(" ")
      $AddRow = $IISLog.newrow()
      for($i=0;$i -lt $Count; $i++) {
        $ColumnName = $Columns[$i]
        $AddRow.$ColumnName = $Row[$i]
      }
      $IISLog.Rows.Add($AddRow)
      }
     $IISLog | select @{n="DateTime"; e={Get-Date ("$($_.date) $($_.time)")}},sip,csuristem,scstatus | ? { $_.DateTime -ge $time } |Out-File C:\Users\Servers\$_results.csv

 }
```

Note that this will run your code sequentially on each of your server wich can be time consumming.  If you are facing duration issue, you can try to use `invoke-command` and the `-asjob` parameter in order to launch you code asynchronoulsy

Comment: Thanks . It is working but sometimes it is getting hanged while running for multiple servers.